# How to handle exceptions when using APScheduler?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, apscheduler

I've just tried to use apsheduler(3.7.0) in Python3.7. I used a 'try/except' clause to handle exceptions in the job, but no exceptions got caught. The code is copied from official examples(which may be a little bit out of date I think)

```py
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

def test():
    print('test')
    raise SystemExit

if __name__ == "__main__":
    scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
    scheduler.add_executor('threadpool')
    scheduler.add_job(test, 'interval', seconds=5)
    try:
        scheduler.start()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        print('caught')
```

The scheduler kept running and the 'caught' never got printed, until I pressed `ctrl+C`. I also tried raising some other kind of exceptions(even `KeyboardInterrupt`), it's still the same.

So did I do it wrong? How should I handle exceptions in the jobs?

Comment: Are you specifically talking about `SystemExit`, or just any exception? It would be a pretty poorly written scheduler if it crashed if any of the jobs raised an unhandled exception.

Comment: @AlexGrönholm Specifically ```SystemExit``` in my use case. I just want to shut down the scheduler when some certain errors occur. I'm now passing the scheduler instance globally into the job to achieve that. Is it a workaround or a right thing to do?

Comment: Using a listener like in my answer below is a better solution because it works even if you use process pool executors or persistent job stores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can be notified if a job raises an exception by means of an event listener:

```
from apscheduler.events import EVENT_JOB_ERROR

def listener(event):
    print(f'Job {event.job_id} raised {event.exception.__class__.__name__}')

scheduler.add_listener(listener, EVENT_JOB_ERROR)
```

Comment: If I want to operate on the scheduler in the callback of the listener, do I still have to use the instance globally?

Comment: You can send additional arguments to the listener callback using `functools.partial()`.